# Mount boot partition on Galaxy S4 (i9500) (CyanogenMod 12.1)

Tags: android, linux, mount, cyanogenmod

I'm interesting in make some changes in init.rc file.
As I have read, I must get copy of boot.img, unpack it, add my changes to init.rc file, pack and push back new boot.img to phone, and after reboot my changes will be considered. (I can't just change init.rc file, that is at / directory, due to it will be rewritten at next reboot.)

So I try:

```
adb shell
 su
 fdisk -l /dev/block/mmcblk0
```

fdisk outputs list of all partition (mounted and unmounted) which are on phone.
I'm intersting in boot:

```
 9          147456          163839       8192K   0700  BOOT
```

where 9 - is partition number, so my partition (device to mount) is /dev/block/mmcblk0p9.

Then I remount rootfs to read/write permissions:

```
mount -o rw,remount rootfs /
```

Create directory (mount point) /boot:

```
mkdir /boot
```

And then try to mount boot partition to /boot:

```
mount -t auto /dev/block/mmcblk0p9 /boot
```

but retrive  "mount: No such device".

Are anybody faced with this ?

Thanks in advance for you help.

PS:
 List of partitions can be also obtained by:

```
 ls -l /dev/block/platform/dw_mmc.0/by-name
```

**Edited:**
I have sources, but I don't want to rebuild their, due to a large amount of time compilation. (I must make many changes in init.rc file and recompile all CyanogenMod it's very expensive).
I have tried to build only module tied, as I think, with init.rc (system/core/rootdir), just type mmp:

```
ila:~/cm_s4/cm_12_1/system/core/rootdir$ mmp
```

and obtained next line:

```
 Install: /home/ila/cm_s4/cm_12_1/out/target/product/i9500/root/init.rc
```

but, no line such as (for example, when I type mmp in external/hello_world):

```
Pushing: /system/bin/hello_world
```

Comment: I have the exact need to use /boot in runtime. Did you manage mounting it ?

Comment: No,  I had another tasks to do :-), but I'll return to this task soon and will write if I have success :-)